# No plot from plotly 4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, rendering, plotly, jupyter-lab

I had been trying to learn how to use `plotly`. I followed all the installation instructions, but when I run the code for the rendering, it just appears a blank space.

I am using `jupyterlab` online, `python 3.6` 
The below code comes from this [link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py)

```
! pip install jupyterlab==1.0 "ipywidgets==7.5"

# Avoid "JavaScript heap out of memory" errors during extension installation
# (OS X/Linux)
! export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096
# (Windows)
! set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096

# Jupyter widgets extension
! jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@1.0 --no-build

# FigureWidget support
! jupyter labextension install plotlywidget@1.1.0 --no-build

# and jupyterlab renderer support
! jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@1.1.0 --no-build

# JupyterLab chart editor support (optional)
! jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-chart-editor@1.2 --no-build

# Build extensions (must be done to activate extensions since --no-build is used above)
! jupyter lab build

# Unset NODE_OPTIONS environment variable
# (OS X/Linux)
! unset NODE_OPTIONS
# (Windows)
! set NODE_OPTIONS=
```

The installation of the extensions seems to be successful because when I check for the available extensions, this is what appears:

[image]

However, when I run the following code it appears a blank space under the cell:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.show()
```

See the output:
[image]

I tried with a lower version of `plotly` , but the issue remains. I also researched and look for an answer over the `plotly` community, but I haven't been successful.

I hope to count with some help.

Comment: I would recommend following the most recent instructions here: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks for the info! I already look at those instructions and is the same to what is described-above.

Comment: I would recommend starting with either a clean environment or uninstalling all Plotly related JLab extensions and trying again, as sometimes remnants from previous installation attempts can prevent them from working.

Comment: Thanks! did it and worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to either start with a clean environment or uninstall all Plotly extensions and modules, and then follow the instructions in https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/

Unfortunately, older versions or the remnants of previous installations can interfere with installation of new versions.